# Split Multidimensional Array

Tags: php

I have an array that looks like this :

`Array 
(
[search_query] =>
   [booklist_id] => 2
   [isbn] => Array ( [0] => 6748305869 [1] => 5749284905 [2] => 3029586930 ))`

I need to know how I can divide this array into 3 separate arrays. I have been trying to figure this out for hours, but I am not having any luck.

If you can point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried that isn't working? You should post what you've tried so we can offer assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This array is not in correct format!!.

```
Array([
    search_query
]=>[
    booklist_id
]=>2[
    isbn
]=>Array([
    0
]=>6748305869[
    1
]=>5749284905[
    2
]=>3029586930))
```

lets start from inside, 
1st array can be,

```
[isbn
]=>Array([
    0
]=>6748305869[
    1
]=>5749284905[
    2
]=>3029586930)
```

2nd array:

```
[
    booklist_id
]=>**Array(**[
    isbn
]=>Array([
    0
]=>6748305869[
    1
]=>5749284905[
    2
]=>3029586930))
```

and third array is whole array